# Why did Ser Gregor do this in Season 8 Episode 5, "The Bells"?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Why did he

> kill Qyburn?

Was that just for stepping beside him and commanding him to listen to Cersei? It felt out of character for such an obedient beast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what i know, Gregor and Sandor really have a hatred to each other, it may be that Gregor had such a blind hatred towards his younger brother that he wouldn't let anything stand in his way. Not even his obedience towards Cersei and Qyburn

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted, because your answer is 100% consistent with the scene. I don't think there's any other explanation, really.

Comment: @AndresF. thx, i was puzzled as well